# PHPMailer shows all recipients in the list when sending an email?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails. I've use it inside a foreach loop in order to send an email to a list of recipients.

It is working, because the email is being sent, but each recipient receives the whole list of recipients!

```
foreach ($id as $item) {
        $mail->addAddress($item);
        $mail->Subject = $correo['mailAsunto'];
        $mail->Body    = $correo['mailMensaje'];
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else { 
          echo 'Mail sent to '.$item.'<br>';
        }
}
```

I've tried: `$mail->AddBCC($item);` instead of `addAddress` but the email can still be seen in the "TO" header.

What may I do? This can have serious privacy implications.

### UPDATE

Just in case anyone has a similar issue, after the responses received, here's how the code is now:

```
foreach ($id as $item) {
        $mail->addAddress($item);
        $mail->Subject = $correo['mailAsunto'];
        $mail->Body    = $correo['mailMensaje'];
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else { 
          echo 'Mail sent to '.$item.'<br>';
                    $mail->ClearAddresses(); 
                    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        }
}
```

Comment: Each time through the loop you are adding another address to the list of recipients. If you want to reuse the `$mail` object while looping, you should clear the recipients after each send by using [clearAddresses](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_clearAddresses)

Comment: For a more complete solution, look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the addresses to the same object, so they are being accumulated. Try deleting each address after sending the message to it:

```
foreach ($id as $item) {
        $mail->addAddress($item);
        $mail->Subject = $correo['mailAsunto'];
        $mail->Body    = $correo['mailMensaje'];
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else { 
          echo 'Mail sent to '.$item.'<br>';
        }
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();    ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
}
```

Comment: After 1 day and 15 hours, finally, your answer saved my life :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this the right PHPMailer github repo, look at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L358. You will want to set that flag to true. Then, wait until after your loop to execute the `send` function.

Comment: linkn is currently broken

Comment: Looks like two things have happened, a refactoring has moved the `SingleTo` flag I mentioned to https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php. Also, it is being deprecated, so use the other solutions

```
* @deprecated 6.0.0 PHPMailer isn't a mailing list manager!
```